# how to integrate when the singularity is right on the integration path

Tags: residue-calculus

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos x}dx
$$
I don't know how to do the integration when the singularity is right on the integration path

Comment: The value is $+\infty$.

Comment: Hint: for small $\epsilon>0$,$$\int_{\pi-\epsilon}^\pi\frac{dx}{1+\cos x}=\int_0^\epsilon\frac12\csc^2\frac{x}{2}dx>\frac12\epsilon\csc^2\frac{\epsilon}{2}>\frac{2}{\epsilon}.$$

Comment: Are you looking for the Cauchy Principal Value or trying to show the integral diverges?